# Is omitting imprts in python for performance reasonable?

Tags: django, python-3.x

So I've been wondering weather neglecting DRY rule instead of importing is good for performance in python and django. I know that when something is imported in python it needs to run it to search for bugs, so what I do here seems reasonable, but I also know that User is imported elsewhere in my project so do I actually gain anything by aproach shown below?

```
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Registration form for User. Import omitted for performance.
    """
    password_1 = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password_2 = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput)

    # class Meta:
    #     model = User
    #     fields = ('username', 'email')
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it needs to run it to search for bugs"?

Comment: If you want to know whether omitting technically-redundant imports impacts performance, you could benchmark with and without them (starting a version control branch for this would give you an easy way to diff and swap the changes in and out for testing). I seriously doubt you'll see any meaningful performance gain, but you _will_ lose readability and possibly make your or others' IDEs unhappy, so I personally wouldn't even bother taking the time to set up a benchmark for this.

Comment: It frequently *boosts* performance to import over defining a new class, since it reduces the memory footprint (and Python is definitely not the most memory-efficient language there is).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem From what Know whenever you import something in python, it loads entire script and runs, and then allows main program to use imported features

Comment: I think you ansewered what i wanted to know, thanks

Comment: @pawqo: yes. But it does that once, you could say it has a "memoize" pattern around it. It is quite likely that somehow it is already imported. For example due to the `'django.contrib.auth'` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`. Furthermore loading a file has some initial cost, but that's it. Defining a second class has more impact on memory, and that will remain, so the overhead is linear with the time the server is running.

Comment: Furthermore usually parsing (for example with a LALR parser) is done in linear time (in the size of the file), so parsing itself is usually quite fast, this will not be a significant overhead, unless the file is gigantic, or triggers loading thousands of extra files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I've been wondering weather neglecting DRY rule instead of importing is good for performance in python and django.

**Usually not**. In fact DRY will frequently *improve* performance. Even if it results in slightly less efficient code, that is only something that usually has a cost when you load the program, so a constant cost, not a linear one.

If you import a module. Python will check if it already has important that module in the first place. In that case it will not load the file again. It simply will pass some references to objects in that module as local variables.

By importing instead of defining a second class (that is almost the same), the memory footprint is smaller. Since you only have one class in memory that you can reuse. It can also slightly improve performance since the chance of ["*cache faults*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) is smaller. It will furthermore result in more interpreted work, especially since modules like `django.contrib.auth.forms` are used a lot, and thus it is very unlikely that it is not loaded at another location.

But DRY is of course mainly a software design principle. The performance improvements are usually not that high (and sometimes indeed could result in some inefficiency). But is usually a lot better to do something good once, instead of trying to implement it multiple times. In your `RegistrationForm`, you in fact have an error here, since you do not check if the passwords match, nor do you set the password with `.set_password(..)`.

Imagine that later you discover a security vulnerability in one of your registration forms, then you will need to change *all* the functions where you introduced that vulnerability. This is a hard problem, since it is definitely possible that you forget some forms, or that you fix some forms the wrong way, and thus introduce even more security vulnerabilities. It furthermore results in a complex codebase. Later when the codebase grows, it makes it harder to undrstand your program, and a future colleague will have a hard time understanding the code base.

Python is not the most efficient language there is. That is partly because of its very dynamic nature. The idea is that  ["*Hardware is cheap, programmers are expensive*" [codinghorror]](https://blog.codinghorror.com/hardware-is-cheap-programmers-are-expensive/). So even if your program is slightly less efficient, that usually does not cost much, since you can buy a faster machine. Taking the last cycles out of a CPU is more expensive, since that will take a lot of programming effort, which is usually more costly than a faster machine.